# Generating regex string to be used in re.match()

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to a string to be used as regex String.
In the following code: 
`_pattern` is a pattern like `abba` and I am trying to check `_string` follows the `_pattern` (eg. `catdogdogcat`)

`rxp` in the following code is the regular expression that I am trying to create to match to `_string` (eg. for above example it will be `(.+)(.+)\\2\\1` ). Which is being successfully generated. But the `re.match()` is returning `None`. 
I want to understand why it is not working and how to correct it ?

```
import re

_pattern = "abba" #raw_input().strip()
_string = "catdogdogcat" #raw_input().strip()
hm = {}
rxp = ""
c = 1
for x in _pattern:
    if hm.has_key(x):
        rxp += hm[x]
        continue
    else:
        rxp += "(.+)"
        hm[x]="\\\\"+str(c)
        c+=1

print rxp
#print re.match(rxp,_string) -> (Tried)  Not working
#print re.match(r'rxp', _string) -> (Tried) Not working

print re.match(r'%s' %rxp, _string) # (Tried) Not working
```

**Output** 
`(.+)(.+)\\2\\1
None`

**Expected Output**
`(.+)(.+)\\2\\1
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000278FE88>`

Comment: Side-note: `dict.has_key` has been deprecated for ages. `hm.has_key(x)` can change to `x in hm` and it runs faster, in a non-deprecated, more consistent with the rest of Python way. Similarly, `not hm.has_key(x)` is better expressed as `x not in hm`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I will remember this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that your regex string variable has double `\\` instead of a single one.

You can use

```
rxp.replace("\\\\", "\\")
```

in `.match` like this:

```
>>> print re.match(rxp.replace("\\\\", "\\"), _string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10bf87c68>

>>> print re.match(rxp.replace("\\\\", "\\"), _string).groups()
('cat', 'dog')
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also avoid getting double `\\` like this:
    import re

```
_pattern = "abba" #raw_input().strip()
_string = "catdogdogcat" #raw_input().strip()
hm = {}
rxp = ""
c = 1
for x in _pattern:
    if x in hm:
        rxp += hm[x]
        continue
    else:
        rxp += "(.+)"
        hm[x]="\\" + str(c)
        c+=1

print rxp
print re.match(rxp,_string)
```

Comment: This is what I guessed too. replace works perfect and serves my purpose also. Can you tell me is there a way to write this so that I can avoid `\\\\' while building the **rxp** only ?

Comment: This is where I did the mistake. Just read that since I was going to use the string in regular expression I don't need to worry about backslashes. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use string formatting, and not hard-code `rxp` into the string:

```
print re.match(r'%s'%rxp, _string)
```

Comment: I tried this too, if this is correct the `_string` should be a match to the regex `rxp` ryt ? But it's not happening.